# execure a storedprocedure with version semicolon in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

How can I execute a stored procedure with version control in my slqdatasource in c#?
I have a large database with a much-stored procedure that is controlled with version control, but I have a problem to execute my SQL data source with this stored procedure.
Here is a sample of my code :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource9" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString.ProviderName %>"                                             
        SelectCommand="SELECT [pyprmtflID], [pt_desc] FROM [Treasury].[STP_T00042005];3">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

With this code, I'm getting error invalid Object name.

Comment: For stored procedure you need to use `EXEC [Treasury].[STP_T00042005];3`

Comment: What is the syntax of exec ? my storedprocedure have some parameter that i fill them on sqldatasourceselecting event.

Comment: You cannot call stored procedure like `SELECT ... FROM proc_name`. You need to use `EXEC proc_name`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Rahul
I found it.
your code is for c# code behind , 
for using in sqldatasource in runtime i have use :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>"   
 SelectCommand="[Treasury].[STP_T00042005];15"  SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
 <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="F_UserId" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="94" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

in my code.
Thank you lad2025.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how stored procedure is executed. You can try like this:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("[Treasury].[STP_T00042005]", conn)) 
{ 
  CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
  {
   conn.Open();
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   conn.Close();
  }
```

Also as lad2015 has said you need to execute the stored procedure using the EXEC command. Try like this

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource9" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString.ProviderName %>"  
    SelectCommand="[Treasury].[STP_T00042005];"  SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```